# Create Document if not exist,otherwise return Null or empty : MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am working on shopping cart project where users can mark items as favorites.if an item is marked as favorite,it will save in my **Favorite** Collection but if he/she already marked that item as favorite,i need to return some response that "This item already marked as favorite" to Mobile Side. 
here i am showing my **favorite** Collection :

```
 [{
   "_id" : "5e6b49162fa5f22c24be54ab",
   "alcoholId" : "5e68ce2c50c82e1abc842f03",
   "mixerId" : "5e68dc5b50c82e1abc860709",
   "barId" : "5e55f10d8b54541278e9cb07",
    "alcoholName" : "Crown Royal",
    "mixerName" : "Ginger beer",
    "modifierList" : [
      {
        "modifierId" : "5e68d38e50c82e1abc84e0e5",
        "_id" : "5e6b49162fa5f22c24be54ac",
        "modifierName" : "Single"
      },
      {
        "modifierId" : "5e68d38e50c82e1abc84e0e5",
        "_id" : "5e6b49162fa5f22c24be54ac",
        "modifierName" : "Single"
      }
   ],
   "customerId" : "5e60cc09387c6c139c458d6a",
   "__v" : 0
},
{
   "_id" : "5e6b49802fa5f22c24be54ad",
   "alcoholId" : "5e68ce3150c82e1abc842fc9",
   "mixerId" : "5e68dc6850c82e1abc8608be",
   "barId" : "5e55f0f28b54541278e9cb06",
   "alcoholName" : "Jameson Irish",
   "mixerName" : "Ginger ale",
    "modifierList" : [
      {
        "modifierId" : "5e68d39350c82e1abc84e1eb",
        "_id" : "5e6b49802fa5f22c24be54ae",
        "modifierName" : "Rocks"
      }
  ],
  "customerId" : "5e60cc09387c6c139c458d6a",
  "__v" : 0
```

}]

if i tried to insert below data again, into my **favorite** Collection,

```
{
"alcoholId" : "5e68ce2c50c82e1abc842f03",
"mixerId" : "5e68dc5b50c82e1abc860709",
"barId" : "5e55f10d8b54541278e9cb07",
"alcoholName" : "Crown Royal",
"mixerName" : "Ginger beer",
"modifierList" : [
    {
        "modifierId" : "5e68d38e50c82e1abc84e0e5",
        "modifierName" : "Single"
    },
    {
        "modifierId" : "5e68d38e50c82e1abc84e0e5",
        "modifierName" : "Single"
    }
],
"customerId" : "5e60cc09387c6c139c458d6a",
"__v" : 0
```

}

should return empty or null.that means, if its not exist inside **favorite** collection,insert it otherwise return null/empty, so that i can identify these already exist in my collection.is it possible to handle in single query without affecting performance.

Comment: any help????????

Comment: Have you tried a unique index?

Comment: no...but i want to check  this in my query..

Comment: If you attempt to insert a second copy in a collection with a unique index, the response will be a 'duplicate key' error that you can catch/handle, and the document will not be inserted.

Comment: so u saying that i should create an unique index for modifierId + mixerId + alcoholId +  barId combination?

Comment: The alternative is to run a query beforehand to make sure it isn't already there.

Comment: Yes...but the problem is how to check that modifier id is already present in modifierlist suddocument.dono how to handle because input data contain  multiple objects under modifierList